# Disable 'Call to a member function *** on null' in PHP?

Tags: php

Very simple question as the title says.

I want PHP to behave rather than give me a error, it might just return another null to me when I called a method on a null object.

PHP on elsewhere looks like it doesn't care anything.

It returns null if you get a non-existed key from a array:

```
$foo = ['foo'=>'foo'];
var_dump($foo['bar']);
```

It returns null even if the array is null:

```
$foo = null;
var_dump($foo['bar']);
```

But it suddenly becomes serious to an object!

Comment: it *does* care and give you a warning - if you correctly set your error_reporting. that aside: it is *your* job as a developer to **check** if you actually have an object or just null.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann A developer job is just get the job done. If this is not able to achieve, just say it.

Comment: an amateurs job is to get the job done. a professionals job is to get the job done *right*. and a simple `if($foo != null)` isn't really that hard.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the error, without saying that disable the report.

```
if ($foo != null) {
    var_dump($foo['bar']);
}
// or
if(isset($foo['bar'])) {
    var_dump($foo['bar']);
}
```